# Append n options to indeterminate number of <select>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to code a  utility for a online gaming community.
use case is

Any hull (container) can hold 0 to 6(slots) of four fixed types. Each hull has armour,weapon,shield an special `slots` . The combination of the slots , varies on the hull type.

the model I am trying to achieve looks like ->

```
 only 1 Container(hull)  having ... 
     Armour 
       Armour 1   - <select>
                     <option 1>
                     <option 2>
                     <option x>
                      </select>

                      ...up to

       Armour 6  - <select>
                      <option 1>
                      <option 2>
                      <option x>
                      </select>   
-------
    Weapon
        Weapon 1    -<select>
                       <option 1>
                       <option 2>
                       <option x>
                       </select>  

                        ...  

        Weapon 2          -<select>
                       <option 1>
                       <option 2>
                       <option x>
                       </select>
```

&etc for the other two types (shield and special)

the "options" for each type are stored in a database and I have coded the necessary queries in a php script. However, to add these(via $. ajax or what not) is proving troublesome.

My issue is ... how to attach the 'options' to the x number of selects for each type? The options are different for each type (armour, weapon, shield, special), and I only know how many of each type, after the hull type has been selected.

I have tried the following (extract) .... without success. Please could one of the gurus on here suggest how to do it... I'd really appreciate the design help 
You'll notice that I use the JFactory, as the whole module is wrapped in Joomla!
Here's my code so far..hope the naming conventions aren't to far out!

```
*/ This is php to create the starting point, the hull.

<php
$hull_sql="SELECT DISTINCT pk,ship_hull FROM ship_hulls";
$db->setQuery($hull_sql);
$results=$db->loadObjectList(); 

echo "<br />Hull: <select id=\"hull".$x."\" onchange=\"getHull(this)\">"; 
       foreach($results as $row) {
        echo"<option value=".$row->pk.">".$row->ship_hull."</option>";}
```

/* the table drawn below shows the user how many slots for the selected hull are
    available */

```
echo"</select>

<table id=\"slotDataTable\">
 <tr>
    <th>Armour Slots</th>
    <th>Shield Slots</th>
    <th>Weapon Slots</th>
    <th>Special Slots</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td id=\"armour\" </td>
    <td id=\"shield\" </td>
    <td id=\"weapon\" </td>
    <td id=\"special\" </td>
</tr>
</table>";

/* this table where the Type selectors are presented */
echo "
<table><td id=\"ArmourData\"></td></tr></table>
<table><td id=\"ShieldData\"></td></tr></table></tr></table>
<table><td id=\"WeaponData\"> </td></tr></table>
<table><td id=\"SpecialData\"> </td></tr></table>";

*/ This is the jquery to make the relevent number of slots */

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getHull(element){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://<mydomian>/get_levels.php",
data:{H:element.value},
success:(function (data_in) 
{
     drawTable(data_in);
})
});
}  
*/ This draws the relevant number of slots    

function drawTable(data_in) {
obj = $.parseJSON(data_in);
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
$("#armour").text(obj[i].armour);
$("#shield").text(obj[i].shield);
$("#weapon").text(obj[i].weapon);
$("#special").text(obj[i].special);
var a=obj[i].armour;
var sh=obj[i].shield;
var w=obj[i].weapon;
var sp=obj[i].special;

}
draw_armour(a);
draw_shield(sh);
draw_weapon(w);
draw_special(sp);
}

function draw_armour(slots){
$('#ArmourData').append("Armour Slot :"+ num+ "&nbsp");   
 // Set options
```

// this is where I get stuck!!!

```
 $.getJSON("http://<mydomain>/get_options.php",{action:getArmour},          
 function (data)
 {
    obj=$.parseJSON(data);
    var html = '<select id=armour'+ num + '>';
    for (var o = 0; o < obj.length; o++) {
    html += '<option value="' + obj[o].value + '">' + obj[o].label + '</option>';
         }
   html +='</select>';
   $('#armour_select' + num).append(html); 
   });
  }
```

---

Please suggest the best approach to populate the options!
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I see one issue right away, since you're using the $.getJSON method the response is already converted to a JSON object when it's passed into your callback function.  Remove the $.parseJSON call and process the response parameter as is and it should work provided the rest of logic is sound.

Another item I noticed is your code to insert the drop down options into the table.   You're using the jQuery text function which basically replaces the target containers contents each iteration through the loop.   Try using the append method instead like so :

```
$('#targetId').append(newHtml);
```

Comment: Thanks for that Brian, I have removed that line now, and processed the `data` object instead. 

Trouble is that it doesn't even seem to make the getJson call. I've been watching with Fiddler. No request or response comes. 

Can you help?

Comment: Where is the event listener  which triggers the ajax call?  With the code you posted the issue is that the AJAX call is never made.  Should the AJAX call execute on page load or use action?  If user action, which action!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand

Comment: What action starts the process?  I can't see in your code where the $.getJSON() method is called.  Usually these are attached to event handlers.  Like when someone clicks a button, or changes a drop down, the code executes.  My question is where in your code does the process of updating the select options occur.

Comment: It's called as part of the draw_armour() function. But as I said, no ajax call is made (fiddler says so). I don't understand why not though. I think where the confusion arises is that I broke the code to say "this is where I get stuck". 
Is it necessary to call this from an event handler, will it not be processed inside a function??

Comment: It will only be executed if the function is called.  Let me put it this way, what user action should trigger the draw_armout() method?

Comment: Yes, I understand. But the function draw_armour(slots) is called, from the previous function  - "drawTable". 

This is done, because before the table is drawn, script will not know how many each armour slot is required on the hull. Hence for example drawArmour(4) means to draw 4 iterations of the select element with id's - armour_select1, armour_select2, armour_select3 and armour_select4. 
 
Each of the 'armour select' iterations have the same values, which come from an ajax call. Getting the data is OK, but appending them is not  - I can't seem to reference those elements??

Comment: So you are getting the response data now, that's where the confusion was.  OK, I'll review and edit post to help you append the response HTML when i get in front of a computer next.

Comment: very much appreciate all the help...I have moved on a little , by adding an event listener ( I used onclick, works but it's not very `elegant`!) 
I have to click in to the select twice for it to render the options -- like something that fell outta the ugli tree, hitting every ugli branch on the way down :)

Comment: Changing the event type from onclick to onchange might make it little less ugly lol

Comment: Unfortunately onchange doesn't seem to trigger the function to pull in the data - **close but no cigar** - I think I know why. at that point, there is nothing for the select element to be 'changed' _to_ as the options are not loaded..and can't be **#Cath22 Situation**

Comment: Good News everyone. 
I hit a couple of problems with onchange, however ...
Problem #1 How to avoid unsightly click, click ... load  
As Brian suggested, change the event listener to use onchange. Triggering this means that (for select elements) you have to first select an opiton value. I created a dummy option, set that value by jquery and then target it. Becasue I used this.id as a prameter to the fucntion , I knew which 'slot' to append to 
`$(target).val('0');
$(target).trigger('change');'

Comment: Problem #2 How to ensure that the options (from ajax were not duplicated on each and every change. 
I counted the number of options ... 
var target='#'+ slot;
var counter=target + " option";
var opts=$(counter).length; 
if (opts == 1)  { //do stuff ` 

... and changed the append method to empty the target element ... 
$(target).empty().append(html);

Comment: So that's it .... 

n iterations of n options. Data comes from ajax / json encoded, so if there are ever more options needed, simply add to the database.